# Checking for Differences Between Docs in Array Embedded Within Another Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to compare two documents (actually the current and previous version of the same record), to determine if the contents of an array on the root of the documents is different. But what I'm *specifically* looking for are changes on an embedded array *within* that root array.

My document structure looks something like this:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  name: { 
    first: "John",
    last: "Smith"
  },
  services: [
    { 
      service: "serviceOne",
      // I want to detect differences at this "history" array level
      history: [ 
        { 
          _id: <ObjectId>,
          title: value
        },
        { 
          _id: <ObjectId>,
          title: value
        }
      ]
    },
    { 
      service: "serviceTwo",
      history: [
        { 
          _id: <ObjectId>,
          title: value
        },
        { 
          _id: <ObjectId>,
          title: value
        }
      ]
    },
  ]   
}
```

How can I check to see if there are differences between the two documents at the level of the "history" array?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I haven't, hence the question. Since I don't know which of the elements in the "services" array may have changed, I'm not sure how to target it in order to check something like length on the "history" array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare the `_id` and `title` of all of them:

```
const compare = cb => (a, b) => a.length === b.length && a.every((el, i) => cb(el, b[i]));
const take = (key, cb) => (a, b) => cb(a[key], b[key]);

const equal = take("services", compare(
  take("history", compare(
    (a, b) => a._id === b._id && a.title === b.title
  ))
))(obj, obj2);
```

Or if the formatting (order of keys) doesn't change between two versions, it can be simplified to:

```
 JSON.stringify(obj) === JSON.stringify(obj2)
```

Comment: Nice! So will this work if the newer document has one additional element in the "history" array, as compared to the earlier document? Because that's the change I will be looking to pick up. So I assumed I would use "length" when at the level of the "history" property.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
function compareObjects(obj1,obj2,reversed){
    for(var key in obj1){
        if(typeof obj2[key]=="undefined") return false
        if(typeof obj1[key] == "object"){
            if(!compareObjects(obj1[key],obj2[key])) return false
        }
        else if(obj1[key]!=obj2[key]) return false
    }
    return reversed ? true : compareObjects(obj2,obj1,true)
}
```

via

```
var new_history = new_document.services.map(service=>service.history)
var old_history = old_document.services.map(service=>service.history)
var are_identical = compareObjects(new_history,old_history)
```

It will look recursively for differences, regardless of the structure.